# subsubsubsubset of subsubsubset of subsubset of subset of set - is this recursive usage normal?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

so I stumbled upon this issue and I cannot find anything that would clear my confusion (as googling "of" is pointless): If I have something, that is of something that is of something - how far can I go with that? In my native languague (Czech), we can say it, because we don't have to insert any word (some equivalent of "of"). But I am not sure that it works the same way in English. So is it normal and correct to use subsubsubset of subsubset of subset of set, or should I rephrase it, and if so, how?
I am asking not only if it is correct, or possible to use but if it "sounds right".

Thanks

EDIT:My mistake, but I wasn't clear enough: I am asking about "of" word, not about "subset" word.

Comment: A subsubset is also a subset of the original set. You don't need the extra "sub". And if you do use it, you should spell it "sub-subset".

Comment: In principle you *can* keep adding more ***sub-*** prefixes in your example - but since they're all contextually implied anyway, I think most people wouldn't bother where there are more than 2 levels. *A subset of a subset of a subset of a subset of a set* is perfectly valid, and a lot less ungainly.

Comment: added edit, I am not asking about subset, but about that multiple usage of "of" word, better example would maybe be something like living creatures of 3rd planet of solar system of the coolest galaxy of the universe.

Comment: a general rule of thumb is that if you are saying 'A of B of C' there is a better way of doing it

Comment: A general rule of thumb is that A of B of C isn't usually so bad, but it gets exponentially worse after C.

Comment: I remember some time around sixth grade reading some kind of semi-legal text for an essay on George Washington, and coming across a rather over-_of_’ed sentence that went something like: “Pursuant to this interpretation of the given version of the intentions of the framers of the constitution of the United States of America, [something something]”. I’m not sure if that’s the kind of thing you’re asking about, or whether you’re specifically talking about mathematical subsets, rather than just possessive constructions in general …

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - ok, so if it was good enough for George Washington, it surely is good enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Gonzi George Washington didn’t write that. It was just a text I happened to come across while reading texts to prepare for writing an essay _about_ George Washington. I have no idea who wrote it. The point it, yes, it’s valid and grammatical. But it’s ugly and inefficient writing, and it is nearly always better to rewrite the sentence to avoid it, unless you’re writing legal documents, where all questions of style go straight out the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: as I misunderstood the question, my new answer is: this is a correct usage of *of*.

*(previous answer retained for posterity)*

---

I believe what you meant was:

> Subset of a subset of a subset of a subset of a set is a *subsubsubsubset* of the set.

What your title describes would be a subsubsubsubsubsubsubsubsubsubset of the set.

However, in this particular instance, the definition of *subset* means that this is actually just called a *subset of a set*, regardless of the number of times you subdivide the set.

Comment: My mistake, but I am asking about "of" word - A of B of C of D.

Comment: Oh! Then yes, absolutely. This is a correct usage of "of".

Comment: Not necessarily. A set is a subset of itself. Though not a proper subset.

Comment: I don't understand your complaint, @Edwin.

Comment: I'll correct myself.  RHK Webster's gives the sense 'proper subset' (ie smaller set) as one of the possible definitions of 'subset', though specifying that this is not the rigorous mathematical definition of 'subset'. But it is an acceptable definition. OP chose an unwise first example.

Comment: Gonzi: 'a subset of subset of subset...' is not correct grammar. It should be 'a subset of _a_ subset of _a_ subset...'

Answer (score 0):

We write X<sub>1</sub> ⊂ X<sub>2</sub> ⊂ ... ⊂ X<sub>*n*</sub> ⊂ ... and we say *a sequence of nested subsets*.

Comment: That doesn't help me, as my example is somewhat confusing ( I am asking about "of" word, if it is ok to use as Human OF earth OF sun OF milky way OF space, if it is used like that "without" limit). That being said, sequence of nested subsets is something, that I will use somewhere else, so thanks for that.